# get names of objects which are in object

Tags: javascript, object

I need to get name of each object which is inside of another object. this should be done in `for` loop like:

```
for (var obj1 in obj2){
    // use obj1.getName
}
```

if this is not possible (but it would be better if yes), I can use something like `name` property for each object in `obj2`. this property will store object name.

basically I dont know why `obj1` is *undefined* when program goes through `for` loop.

**EDIT:** problem with *undefined* was in firebug breakpoint on `for` header row. it missed some code and show me *undefined*

Comment: Can you post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with the declaration of your object? Or maybe post it inside the question

Comment: May be you have missed something

Comment: If `obj1` really is undefined than that's would be a really weird behaviour since the for loop is only looping through properties that actually exist. Or is it that just `obj1.getName` is undefined?

Comment: @koubin your solution is as weird as your problem :)

Comment: @basilikum it was another problem. I commented it in edited question, sorry :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating in a `for..in` loop like that, you will see `obj1` is assigned to each key in sequence, which means you can get the value as `obj2[obj1]`. That's all there is to it, it couldn't be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to select a dynamic key in an object you use the array notation like so:

```
for (var obj1 in obj2){
    obj2[obj1]
}
```